# while converting div to pdf &nbsp; is showing , how to remove nbsp and replace with space in itext sharp pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i have one div in that lots of nbsp is there to give space in div . while converting div to  pdf `&nbsp;` is showing , how to remove nbsp and replace with space in itext sharp pdf. i need space between

**aspx**

```
 <td style="border: 1px solid" colspan="2">Employee Code `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`:<span id="spanEmployeeCode" runat="server">P12215882</span><br />
**code behind**     
Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}.pdf\"", Projname));

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(myText.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.End();
    pdfDoc.Dispose();
```

Comment: It's because of this: `string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");`. **Remove** the `.Replace("&", "&amp;")`, and you'll have spaces instead of the literal string `&nbsp;` in the PDF like you want.

Comment: Or if you **must** replace `&`, then do this instead: `string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("&amp;nbsp;", "&nbsp;")`

Comment: thanks a lot for ur kind help.....

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd put the answers found in the comments as a proper answer for the benefit of all the future readers. Right now, your code doesn't know that `&nbsp;` is one thing. It views it as 6 separate characters. On this line:

```
string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
```

You're replacing every `&` with `&amp;`, causing every instance of `&nbsp;` to turn into `&amp;nbsp;`. That's definitely not what you want, because when the PDF is created, it'll recognize `&amp;` as an ampersand and not recognize the non-breaking space. Try what @kuujinbo said:

```
string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("&amp;nbsp;", "&nbsp;")
```

This will find all the times that you accidentally replaced an ampersand where it shouldn't have been replaced, and fix it. Then your non-breaking spaces will show up how they're supposed to.

This also applies to many other languages as it's more of a concept than a language-specific syntax thing. I had the same problem in JavaScript and fixed it using this method.